# Django 1.6 TypeError render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I'm trying to show all the waiting times associated to a doctor in my template. But I get this error. I'm very new to django so I'm not sure what to change.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "views.py" in showDocProfile
  69.     return render(request,'meddy1/docprofile.html',{'doctor': profile}, {'timeList': WaitingTime.objects.all()})
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),

Exception Type: TypeError at /docprofile/1/
Exception Value: render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Here is the view.py where I'm trying to save all the waiting time objects

```
def showDocProfile(request, id):
    profile = Doctor.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'meddy1/docprofile.html',{'doctor': profile}, {'timeList': WaitingTime.objects.all()})
```

Here is the template docprofile.html where I'm trying to show the waiting times

```
{% for t in timeList %}
  <h4>{t.time}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class WaitingTime(models.Model):
    time_choices = ( (10, 'Less than 10 Minutes'), (20, 'Less than 20 Minutes'), (30, 'Less than 30 Minutes'))
    time = models.IntegerField(choices = time_choices, blank = True )
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    doctor_seeker = models.ForeignKey(DoctorSeeker)
    date = models.DateField()

class Doctor(models.Model):
    avg_times = models.ManyToManyField(DoctorSeeker, through="WaitingTime")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    language = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
    education1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    education2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
    gender_choices = ( ('M', 'Male'), ('F','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices = gender_choices, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='/uploads/', null=True)
    statement = models.TextField(null=True)
    affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your call to `render()` you are passing 2 dicts, rather you need to pass 1 dict with both items, which is taken as context for the template.

Update your all to

```
return render(request,'meddy1/docprofile.html',
          {'doctor': profile, 
           'timeList': WaitingTime.objects.all()
          })
```

Comment: Even if you are passing a Constant from the "settings.py", you have to include it in the same dict and not create two. Example: return render(request,'meddy1/docprofile.html',
          {'doctor': profile, 
           'debugMod': settings.DEBUG
          }). In your template: {{debugMod}}

Answer (score 1):

`doctor` and `timelist` need to be in the same dictionary, not separate ones.

```
return render(request,'meddy1/docprofile.html',{'doctor': profile, 'timeList': WaitingTime.objects.all()})
```